# Finding column to paste starting at row

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I have been looking for some time now and I see posts concerning pasting an entire column starting at a specific row, but in my case my column is based on an if statement for a value. I am still an amateur so i'm guessing the answer has to do with setting an `i` somewhere to find the correct column, but I do not know how to incorporate that in my case. The code below works I just do not know how to copy starting at row 3 instead of using `EntireColumn`. Thank you for the help and let me know if I left any information out.

```
    Sub ColumnCopy()

For Each cell In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5:AZ3000")
    If cell.Value = "Active" Then Cell.EntireColumn.Copy Destination:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Columns(2)
Next

 End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe you should take a step back and explain what the problem is. Do you really need to loop through all these cells? Is there only one instance of `Active` that you are looking for? If there is more than one, you are just copy/pasting over the same column time and time again

Comment: Copying from row 3 down to the last row would also work perfectly. There is just one column labeled `Active`.

Comment: So you want to find the column header named `Active`, then copy from row 3 down to last row. You then want to paste this column where? What range, `B3`?

Comment: Yes, I would then want to paste this column to Sheet2, B3.

Comment: My column headers in Sheet1 are on row 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would amend some options to the `Range.Find` method. Case sensitive? Look in `xlPart` or `xlWhole`? Etc. This is currently set to search from `Columns A - Z` to find `Active`. You can extend this if needed

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindHeader()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim Found As Range, LRow As Long

Set Found = ws.Range("A5:Z5").Find("Active")

If Not Found Is Nothing Then
    LRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, Found.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(3, Found.Column), ws.Cells(LRow, Found.Column)).Copy
    ThisworkBook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you I will give this a try and then update. Simple question: on the last line is it pasting to Sheet2?

Comment: Now it is ;) Good catch.

Comment: Awesome, I was second guessing myself. I'll be back with an update.

Comment: Great timing, literally just about to comment, worked perfectly thank you so much for your help and time.